# Put one fragment in another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragment(frag1) and I want to place another fragment(frag2) in it. So in XML file of frag1 I place

```
        <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment4"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment1" />
```

but when I start app I get this problem:

```
Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: please post your full xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have a fragment A and fragment B. If you want to put fraagment B inside A do this in Fragment A

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    Fragment profileFragment = new FragmentB();//the fragment you want to show
                    profileFragment.setArguments(null);
                    fragmentTransaction
                            .add(R.id.container, profileFragment);//R.id.content_frame is the layout you want to replace
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Just wrap the view around a frame layout on which you need to place your fragment B.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <...>  // The view over which you want your fragment
</FrameLayout>
```

Note that the id of this frame layout is the same which I have passed inside the add method above.

Comment: @mikery , did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **Fragment** in xml use **FrameLayout** for replace and add fragment in **Activity**, see the following link might be helpful

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html